# Why can't I access class variables in function in Powershell 5?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to define a class in Powershell v5 and I can't access variables from within class functions.

Ex.

```
PS C:\> class Foo{
          $bar = 'foobar'
          mymethod(){
            $bar + '123'
          }
        }
PS C:\> [Foo]::new().mymethod()
PS C:\> At line:4 char:11
        +           $bar + '123'
        Variable is not assigned in the method.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `$this` to access your variable:

```
class Foo{
      $bar = 'foobar'
      [string] mymethod(){
        return $this.bar + '123'
      }
    }
```

Output:

```
foobar123
```